# How can I get two elements to be on the same height?

Tags: html, css, layout, formatting

I am currently working on a website and was wondering if You could help me solve a problem. I want the h1 title to be **on the same line** as the date but I can't get it to work for some reason.

The CSS code:

```
    #content h1 {
    font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
    color: #262626;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    float: left;
}

.date {
    float: right;
}
```

The HTML code:

```
<body>
        <nav>
            <a href='#' class='active'>Home</a>
            <a href='#'>Partners</a>
            <a href='#'>Contact</a>
            <a href='#' class='about'>About</a>
        </nav>

        <div id='content'>
            <h1>Welcome.</h1>
            <p class='date'>01/01/2016</p>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Help is appreciated. :)

Comment: What do you mean by `on the same line` - You have wildly different margins and padding the heading. How is this supposed to look?

Comment: I created a JsFiddle of the page, here: https://jsfiddle.net/kkLb3yay/1/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are looking for is floats:

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rodsbrsw/)

```
 .alignleft {
     float: left;
 }

 .alignright {
     float: right;
 }
```

The reason why they  aren't completely right on each other, is that your welcome is a h1 and it has got some bigger styling than the p does. Could be solved with some custom styling.

You can read more about left and right aligning [here](https://css-tricks.com/left-align-and-right-align-text-on-the-same-line/)

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

just add `margin: 0` to `h1` and `p`

```
#content h1 {
    font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
    color: #262626;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}

.date {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/snv3992k/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code on following problem I got
You added one css propertie for h1 tag i.e  `margin-top: 50px;`

as per you applied float , but you not applied  `margin-top: 50px;` for .date class
just add code

```
.date {
margin-top: 50px;
float: right;
```

}

Comment: You can adjust this properties as you result expect i.e **margin-top** value;